# Google Account automatic logout every one or two days

Tags: google-account

I have a Google account that I keep permanently logged in on two computers + an android phone.

On one of them I get signed out every one or two days, while on the other I'm signed in all the time (unless I log in or the cookie expires - once a month or so).

I've checked the account activity (the bottom link in Gmail) and there are no signs of weird account activity; it's got traffic just from these two IPs and my mobile.

Has anyone else experienced weird log-offs like these? Is there any particular reason why it may behave like this?

**Update**
I just noticed this: while I'm experiencing the logout of iGoogle in my Chrome browser, I can go to Gmail (by entering the address in the address bar) and I'm logged in.

Comment: Are you using two-factor authentication?

Comment: Yes, I use the 2-step verification functionality.

Comment: You have to organize your content if anyone is to reproduce the error. Which one of them do you get signed out of? Logged out of iGoogle where? The Android phone? Which browsers?

Comment: @phwd I just edited the question: it happens in my Chrome browser. Apparently, the authentication cookies that Google uses for different services have different validity durations

Answer (score 1):

I use Chrome and iPhone 4 and haven't had this problem. Well, maybe once I think. But nothing annoying. If your settings in your browser is correct. And you have selected the remember me setting for your google account. The only thing I've found in researching the issue is to go to this link

"http://www.gmail.com/gmail&service=mail&[email address]&Passwd=YOURPASSWORD&null=Sign+in

I got this from this chat room with a slew full of people having the same issue as you.

https://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/m/#!topic/sites/VTdw4eFnmF0

I'll try to figure something else if it doesn't work. Or someone else can hopefully answer.

Comment: +1 Thanks for your research, Tremaine. Yes, I have checked the 'remember me' box. If I restart the browser I'm logged in. It's usually one or two days that the log off happens. For me it's not that annoying, because it's not very often.

Comment: I'll look again.